# How to solve ode when "The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2." occur?

Tags: python, ode

I'm trying to solve ODE with odeint.

My code is like this

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

K = 35.94143542
S = 10
M = 30.03
Vr = 58
R = 8.3145
T = 293.15
Q = 0.4998
Vp = 0.000022
Mr = 18
Pvap = 518624.013
Cv = (40000/0.000022)*0.001
Cr = (40000/0.000022)*(1-0.001)
tr = 0.333333333

t = np.arange(0,4+1e-2,1e-2)

def Cair(C, t):
    if t <= tr:
        dCdt = ((K*S*M*Peq)/(Vr*R*T))-(((K*S)/Vr)+Q)*C
    else:
        dCdt = -(((K*S)/Vr)+Q)*C
    return dCdt        

Peq = (Cv*Pvap)/(Cv+Cr*(M/Mr))

C = odeint(Cair, 0 , t) 

plt.plot(t, C)

def Cvt(c, t):
    dcdt = -((K*S*M)/(Vp*R*T))*(Peq-((C*R*T)/M))
    return dcdt   
s = (K*S*M)/(Vp*R*T)
p = ((K*S*M)/(K*S*R*T+Vr*R*T*Q))*((Cv*Pvap)/(Cv+(Cr*M/Mr)))
q = ((K*S)/Vr)+Q
init = ((s*p*R*T)/M)*(1+(1/q))  
c = odeint(Cvt, init, t)
plt.plot(t, c)
```

I successfully solve and draw first equation and graph(Cas function by t), But I failed to solve second equation and draw the graph(c as function by t)

How to do it?

Comment: The argument is lower-case `c` in `Cvt`, however in the formula for `dcdt` you use uppercase `C` which at that point is the result of the previous `odeint` run, thus an array.

Comment: So how to fix it?

Comment: By correcting the error and replacing uppercase by lowercase `c`.

Comment: I have to use function C to solve Cvt. How can i insert function C properly?

Comment: Please post the error with the error stack.

Comment: Do you mean that in the second equation you use the value `C(t)`, where `t :-> C(t)` is the solution of the first system? There is interpolation or treating the whole as a coupled system.

Comment: Oh. I solved with different way. Anyway, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer won't help you find the issue but I need to tell you that this code is particulary confusing !

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores. Variable names follow the same convention

So no var C and c or T and t even if it is math or physic constants and name it !

You shouldn't use variable that are not passed to the function. I don't understand the goal of using 2 functions in this code sample as it is only called once.

Also the name of the var in the function can be diffrent to the name you call the function with. So don't hesistate to write what each var is in the function, it is easier to understand.

```
def calculate_distance(speed, time):
    return speed*time

s = 30
t = 1
calculate_distance(s, t)
```

SO that said :

```
# variables
r = 8.3145
t = 293.15
q = 0.4998
...

# list all var you need here
def calculate_dcdt(c, t, tr, k ... q):
    if t <= tr:
        dcdt = ((k*s*m*peq)/(vr*r*t))-(((k*s)/vr)+q)*c_1
    else:
        dcdt = -(((k*s)/vr)+q)*c_1
    return dcdt        

def calculate_cvt(c, t, k, ... peq):
    dcdt = -((k*s*m)/(vp*r*t))*(peq-((c_1*r*t)/m))
    return dcdt 

peq = (vv*pvap)/(cv+cr*(m/mr))    
c_1 = odeint(calculate_dcdt, 0 , t) 
...
```

Comment: Oh. I solved with different way. Anyway, thanks for your help